# WKHTMLTOPDF difficulty displaying MultiColor SVG in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, svg, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` to generate PDF from HTML. The PDF has Order Estimate details and styling layout with single/multicolor. I am using wkhtmltopdf on Mac OS.

I have an `Multicolor SVG` image converted to `BASE64`.
The image displays the base64 data properly on webpage, however, when that base64 is used to display in PDF. It doesn't show up. Below is the MultiColor SVG which is **not getting displayed** on PDF.
[image]

For a single color SVG image the display is proper. Below image with single color, gets printed on PDF properly. [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1975